# The Listener is null in my RecyclerView On Item Click Listener

Tags: java, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

i'm try using an On item click listener in a Recycler view, but when i click on items nothing happens even if i have no error while compiling, so i puted Break points and it shows me that the listener is always null even if he's initialized in the Adapter constructor.
I'm following this tutorial https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/

1.In the adapter :

`public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<Device> devices;
private OnItemClickListener listener;

public MyAdapter(List<Device> devices, OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.devices = devices;
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

...

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Device device);
}`
```

2.in the view Holder :

`void display(Device device, MyAdapter.OnItemClickListener listener) { //method Bind

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener( v ->
            listener.onItemClick( device ) );
```

...`

3.In the Main Activity :

`RecyclerView.setAdapter( new MyAdapter( devices, item ->
                Toast.makeText( getContext(), "Item Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show()
        ) );`

When i click on items i must have a toast

Comment: follow link of video tutorial, It will help you. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=69C1ljfDvl0 @anonymous